# What does 'a fool in school for cutting gym' mean?

Tags: mulan

In the *Mulan* movie, there's a song called "Be a Man", sung by Donny Osmond as Shang.

At one point, different trainees say an individual line (1:35 in the above video):

> I'm never gonna catch my breath
>   Say goodbye to those who knew me
>   Boy, was I a fool in school for cutting gym
>   This guy's got 'em scared to death
>   Hope he doesn't see right through me
>   Now I really wish that I knew how to swim

What does "Boy, was I a fool in school for cutting gym" mean? This doesn't seem to make any sense.

Comment: The trainee says he skipped gym classes in school, and thus he is now not in good enough shape. What about this doesn't make sense?

Comment: Well, "cutting" gym, as in 'not attending the class' is a US term which may not be understood by even other native English speakers.

Comment: @BCdotWEB - because I've never heard the term 'cutting' used that way.

Comment: .... which proves my point ;)

Comment: @Tetsujin - heh. Yeah. I'm American, but haven't lived there in years and I've never attended school past Kindergarten.

Comment: I'm not American, and English was the fourth language I learned. I probably know what "cutting" means in this context due to watching a ton of movies and TV shows, so to me it is a fairly common term.

Comment: They had gym class in ancient China?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

They are doing physical training in preparation of war. He is regretting *cutting* gym as it would have helped him to be more prepared for the intense training he is now going through.

EDIT: The term *cutting* is slang in the UK and the US for not attending something you are supposed to, generally in reference to school. aka "I'm *cutting* class this afternoon" or "I'm going to *cut* gym tomorrow"

Comment: US only, not UK [unless it's been adopted here since I left school ;) but ty for the edit.

Comment: @Tetsujin I'm from the UK, I'm 26 now so it has been a while since I was in school. We didn't use the slang directly but we knew of it. I'm fairly certain I had a friend go "oh my god, you're cutting class" at some point.

Comment: We use it here in Canada as well! "Cutting class", "Blowing off class", "Skipping class", etc...